# NPM unknown protocol

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When I run `npm install` I get following error. It seems it can't download any package. I use node 8.2.1 and npm 5.3.0

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

```
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.5.1.tgz failed,
reason: write EPROTO 140640770651968:error:140770FC:SSL 
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:797:
```

npm logs:

```
0215 verbose type system
20216 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.5.1.tgz failed, reason: write EPROTO 140640770651968:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:797:
20216 verbose stack
20216 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (/home/pawel/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
20216 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
20216 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:7)
20216 verbose stack     at onerror (/home/pawel/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/node_modules/agent-base/index.js:106:9)
20216 verbose stack     at callbackError (/home/pawel/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/node_modules/agent-base/index.js:126:5)
20216 verbose stack     at <anonymous>
20217 verbose cwd /home/pawel/work/react-components
20218 verbose Linux 4.4.0-83-generic
20219 verbose argv "/home/pawel/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/bin/node" "/home/pawel/.nvm/versions/node/v8.2.1/bin/npm" "install"
20220 verbose node v8.2.1
20221 verbose npm  v5.3.0
20222 error code EPROTO
20223 error errno EPROTO
20224 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.5.1.tgz failed, reason: write EPROTO 140640770651968:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:797:
20225 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Are you behind any proxy?

Comment: no, I don't use any proxy.

Comment: Can you try to install 32-bit version of Node.js.  Its available here https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: In which port your app is listening?

Comment: compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421050. Why does your machine try to use the long-deprecated SSLv2? TLS installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install without ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874363/npm-install-without-ssl)

Answer (score 9):

I also had this problem. The following trick has worked for me.

It would be better if you upgrade your `node` and `npm` versions to latest. After that please follow the below steps.

Try running `curl https://registry.npmjs.org/package-name` from your terminal to make sure that network call is not blocking the package requests to `npm` registry.

If you are running behind a `proxy`, then you also have to configure `npm` to use it, and you can set it using:

`npm config set proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport`

`npm config set http-proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport`

`npm config set https-proxy http://proxyhost:proxyport`

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Hope the above trick resolve your issue.