# npm install failed EPROTO fetch request failed

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I get fetch failed error when I try to install a package from npm. I set the config of the npm: 
 - set strict-ssl to false
 - set registry with https://registry.npmjs.org/
 - set the proxy and https-proxy

When I search a package, the get method to the registry worked fine however when I try to install, I got an error

I got this error after I upgrade my node with the last version of Node 8.9.1 with npm 5.5.1.

I tried many things to fix it:
 - deleted the content and reconfigured my .npmrc settings with proxy, strict-ssl
 - downgrade to my latest version which was the node 4 version however it doesn't work ....

This is the error that I got:

> info it worked if it ends with ok
>   verbose cli [ 'C:\Applications\Nodejs\node.exe',
>   verbose cli
>   'C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>   verbose cli   'install',
>   verbose cli   'create-react-class',
>   verbose cli   '--save',
>   verbose cli   '--verbose' ]
>   info using npm@5.5.1
>   info using node@v4.7.0
>   verbose npm-session 3edca0dd78623f79
>   silly install loadCurrentTree
>   silly install readLocalPackageData
>   silly fetchPackageMetaData error for create-react-class@latest request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-class failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794:
>   verbose type system
>   verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-class failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794:
>   verbose stack
>   verbose stack     at ClientRequest. (C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
>   verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>   verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
>   verbose stack     at onerror
>   (C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\index.js:106:9)
>   verbose stack     at callbackError (C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\node_modules\agent-base\index.js:126:5)
>   verbose cwd D:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\Documents\PycharmWorkspace\
>   verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   verbose argv "C:\Applications\Nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "create-react-class" "--save" "--verbose"
>   verbose node v4.7.0
>   verbose npm  v5.5.1
>    error code EPROTO
>    error errno EPROTO
>   error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-class failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL  routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794:
>    verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM unknown protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547306/npm-unknown-protocol)

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I fix the problem by completely removing node.js and npm from my computer following this post [How to completely remove node.js from Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows)

Comment: _Hmmm, this looks like a problem..._ <proceeds to uninstall> _Problem solved!_ -- I am guessing you reinstalled it afterwards?