# Issue with npm install

Tags: node.js

Can someone help on the below error

```
npm install nightwatch --save 
ERR! code EPROTO 
npm ERR! errno EPROTO 
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/nightwatch failed, reason: write 
EPROTO 101057795:error:14077419:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert access denied:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:802: 
npm ERR!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install failed EPROTO fetch request failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206374/npm-install-failed-eproto-fetch-request-failed)

Comment: When you ask question make sure you provide enough context on what you want to do and the things you have tried before.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that npm at the end? I've never seen that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `npm install nightwatch --save npm` for your npm installation, use `npm install nightwatch --save`. This should solve your problem