# Issues while installing ionic - 'EPROTO'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

When I install ionic I get the following error:

> npm ERR! code EPROTO npm ERR! errno EPROTO npm ERR! request to
> https://registry.npmjs.org/async-limiter/-/async-limiter-1.0.0.tgz
> failed, reason: write EPROTO 0:error:140770FC:SSL
> routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
> protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:827: npm ERR!

I'm using windows 10 in a network whose server runs Ubuntu-16.
I'm behind a proxy and set the parameters as below:

```
$ npm config set proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
$ npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM unknown protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547306/npm-unknown-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

It should be `http-proxy-` instead of just `proxy`.

```
npm config set http-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
```