# NodeJS SSL options - strictSSL vs rejectUnauthorized

Tags: node.js, ssl

What is the difference between **strictSSL=false** and **rejectUnauthorized=false** options in NodeJS?

The names are confusing and I did not find documentation, explaining the difference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31862256/5617140

Comment: Well, and what is the difference with strictSSL=false ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these two flag options are used in different context and are not exactly comparable.  On one hand, you can look at **rejectUnauthorized=false** flag in node **runtime context** which does as quoted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31862256/5617140) answer :

> By setting rejectUnauthorized: false, you're saying "I don't care if I
>   can't verify the server's identity." Obviously, this is not a good
>   solution as it leaves you vulnerable to MITM attacks.

Whereas you can look at **strictSSL=false** as more **build and setup context** as this is the flag you pass to npm when installing dependencies from an HTTP source rather than https as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48065862/5617140) post.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that **strictSSL** is part of the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package and **rejectUnauthorized** is a native property of NodeJS. Both do the exact same thing in the end though. In the request package, rejectUnauthorized is set to false when strictSSL is set to false, which you can see [here](https://github.com/request/request/blob/3c0cddc7c8eb60b470e9519da85896ed7ee0081e/request.js#L254).