# Why is npm config using https and not http for the registry?

Tags: npm

I set my npm registry with

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I then run

```
install -g redis-cli
```

and get the error

```
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/redis-cli failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Why is npm requesting `https://registry.npmjs.org/redis-cli` and not `http://registry.npmjs.org/redis-cli` after setting it to the http url?

If I run `npm config ls -l` I do see

```
; "user" config from /Users/grant.spilsbury/.npmrc
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
; "cli" config from command line options
```

Comment: Does the comment under the answer, answer your question? [npm install without ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874363/npm-install-without-ssl)

Comment: I have done that by running npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/